# Can't add website URL

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

I'm trying to fill the "Web site URL" on my [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) profile, and I keep getting an "Email is already registered" error.

I think it's because my OpenID, website URL and email are all the same or almost:

- OpenID: http://javier.guerrag.com
- website: http://javier.guerrag.com
- email: javier@guerrag.com

or maybe it's a conflict with some other account I unwillingly created?

Comment: Where do you get that error message, on _Stack Overflow_?

Comment: On _Stack Overflow_, that is the website I see on your account.

Comment: sorry, it's on careers.stackoverflow.  i pressed the 'support' button and landed here.  didn't realize it's the 'normal' meta.stackoverflow and not 'meta.careers.stackoverflow'.  question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error pops up when you have two (or more) accounts. I've merged yours so you should be good to go.